How to obtain differential measurements with an ADC
I have a digital scope and it has also differential inputs(+in_Scope and -in_Scope). I always obtain less noisy results using them comparing to and single ended wiring. Here below I draw what I mean:

If I do the wiring as in Figure 1, I get much better results than in Figure 2. I think Figure 1 is called pseudo-differential connection and Figure 2 is like single-ended connection. One thing I don't know, whether the reason for more noise in Figure 2 is common mode noise converted to differential noise due to imbalance or it is differential noise. Probably in Figure 2 it is CM interference appearing as differential noise. Can this be the reason?
Now I want to couple the circuit to this MCU board(F303-K8) instead of the scope. But it seems the the ADC of the MCU has only single ended input. Is there a common remedy for the MCU case making its ADC inputs acting like differential inputs?
(Signal to be monitored is a DC voltage signal from a sensor with response time of 5ms in case it varies.)


Is there a common remedy for the MCU case making its ADC inputs acting
like differential inputs?

Yes, it's called a differential amplifier and can be made from an Instrumentation amplifier: -

Or, it can be made from from an op-amp using an additional 4 resistors: -


One thing I don't know, whether the reason for more noise in Figure 2
is common mode noise converted to differential noise due to imbalance
or it is differential noise.

It could be that or, it could also be ground/earth loop currents (remember that your oscilloscope is earthed).

Could you provide an answer showing how my single-ended circuit is
coupled/wired to both of your suggestions?

If you want a single-ended supply for your differential amplifier, the only one that can be guaranteed to work (in most scenarios) is this circuit: -

Operating with a single rail op-amp isn't guaranteed to work in all scenarios but, it will perform better than a single-rail instrumentation amplifier due to the indirect coupling of op-amp inputs via resistors. I would highly recommend that you use a simulator to establish whether either of the solutions proposed will work with a single-rail supply. If necessary, raise a new post for further analysis.

My circuit's op-amp is single supply 5V powered and the DC signal
output swings from zero to 3V max. Do I need negative rail for those diff op-amps?

It might be inevitable that you will need a negative rail. It all depends on how different the two ground voltages actually are. Once again, simulation is key to the analysis.

@user1245 In addition, some MCUs can configure two inputs to an ADC as differential inputs. You must read the datasheet to determine how this is implemented, if at all.

FYI my scope is not earth grounded. I was trying to avoid extra active components.

@Andy Aka In my case if V1 is connected to my circuit output signal should the V2 be connected to my circuit's ground? My single-ended circuit has only Vout and GND as terminals. But your second opamp has three inputs V1, V2 and GND. Could you provide an answer showing how my single-ended circuit is coupled/wired to both of your suggestions?

@user1245 yes, if you are referring to my first image. However, you have to be careful about the power supply connections in that circuit; you must ensure that the op-amp power supply negative voltage is more negative than the 0 volts you are measuring by at least 1 volt. Conversely, the differential amplifier (shown in my 2nd image can deal with negative voltage a little bit better. It all depends on the details not indicated in your question.

My circuit's opamp is single supply 5V powered and the DC signal  output swings from zero to 3V max. Do I need negative rail for those diff opamps?

@user1245 extra parts added to my answer.

Figure 1 and figure 2 have the same problem, it's just that in Figure 1 the problem is sidestepped.
You perhaps imagine things look as on the left below, but they actually look more like on the right below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In spite of the non-idealities above, the scope still measures \$V_{src}\$, assuming that \$Z_{in,SCOPE}\gg Z_{cable}\$.
Then, when a single-ended connection is used:

simulate this circuit
Or, equivalently:

simulate this circuit
What you end up measuring on the scope is \$V_{src}+(Z_{cable}||Z_{PE})\,I_{PE}\$.
So, what's the solution when connecting the circuit to an ADC with single ended inputs? Ensure that at least one side is not connected to PE:

simulate this circuit
If that's not possible, then:

Break the ground loop next to the ADC by adding an isolation impedance \$Z_{iso}\gg Z_{cable}\$.

Add a voltage-controlled voltage source to have the ADC measure the voltage on the source in spite of being ground-referenced.



simulate this circuit
The VCVS can be easily implemented using an instrumentation amplifier. The isolation impedance \$Z_{iso}\$ is then the input impedance of the in-amp.

simulate this circuit
The classical in-amps that have equivalent three-op-amp architecture have a low impedance REF input. It can only be connected to a low-impedance node - an op-amp output or a ground.
In some cases, due to output voltage range limitations of the in-amp, its output may need to be "centered" around a voltage above the COM terminal of the ADC. In that case, it should always be ratiometrically derived from the ADC's reference voltage - that way it will have negligible thermal drift as long as R1 and R2 are tracking each other well.
The in-amp's input common mode voltage range needs to be wide enough that it will contain \$\Delta V_{PE}\$. This interfering ground voltage has AC and DC components that can reach several V within a small building, or much more across larger industrial buildings.
There are in-amps with wide input common mode voltage ranges that extend beyond supply voltages. You'll need to specify the maximum allowed \$\Delta V_{PE}\$ that your data acquisition system will be able to compensate for, and design accordingly.

Both sides are not connected to PE in my case. I dont have such ground  loops. Im trying to understand your answer though. I dont think I have IPE1 and IPE2 since I dont have such common earth conenction.
